# Trouble building gcc 4.6: undefined reference to `yylex'

Tags: gcc, makefile, bison

I'm trying to build gcc 4.6, but I'm getting some linker errors that look like it means bison or flex isn't getting linked to. When the makefile issues this command:

```
gcc   -g -fkeep-inline-functions -DIN_GCC   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wc++-compat -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/gengtype \
        build/gengtype.o build/errors.o build/gengtype-lex.o build/gengtype-parse.o build/version.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
```

It tells me:

```
/home/chris/code/gcc/trunk/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/gengtype.c:960: undefined reference to `lexer_line'
... undefined reference to `yylex'
... undefined reference to `yybegin'
... undefined reference to `yyend'
```

I've installed Flex and Bison, and even tried several Bison variants with the same result. Does anybody know what else this might mean?

Comment: Which versions of flex, bison and other tools have you used?  Was the same error occurring at every such attempt?  Some old discussions that Google finds for _gengtype.c undefined reference to `lexer_line'
... undefined reference to `yylex'_ points to a possible problem with flex.  Are you building from the svn trunk?  Or from some distribution's source repository?

Comment: The same happened to me. Is this some kind of bug that first itme installation will not work properly?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Same happened to me, it was due to lack of flex and bison. After installing flex and bison, I ran `make distclean` and `./configure`, then it compiled fine.

Comment: Aha, make *distclean*.  I'd tried just a `make clean`, but that didn't work.  I was about to try nuking from orbit like @Chris suggested, but this worked just as well.

Comment: For the record this was the fix for a standard Ubuntu install (11.04)

Comment: The gcc installation docs recommend not running configure in the source dir. If you run ../gcc-srcdir/configure from a different dir then the source dir remains untouched and you can just remove the whole obj dir. That is more reliable (and faster) than "make distclean"

Comment: Why does configure not warn about the lack of flex? It [was so picky with GMP!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253695/building-gcc-requires-gmp-4-2-mpfr-2-3-1-and-mpc-0-8-0)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this as well, but the fix for me was to install `bisonc++`. For whatever reason, I only had `bison` installed.

Comment: I don't understand why this was down voted, this helped me out trying to compile a gcc 6 snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

It just got into some weird state since I did ./configure and tried to build it before having bison and flex set up properly. Calling make clean wasn't enough. I wiped out the whole thing and did a fresh checkout and it builds fine now.