# ad hoc install iphone app using Ubuntu

Tags: ios, ubuntu, itunes, ipa, adhoc

The single way, as I understand, can be drag&drop `.ipa` file to iTunes app on laptop while iphone is connected. I tried to install iTunes on Ubuntu, but as there is no linux version, I try with wine/playonlinux. In [`playonlinux`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414737/how-do-i-install-itunes-on-ubuntu) I tried different versions of iTunes from [official website](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#itunes). For version 11.1.5 32 bit it says that iTunes Library.itl file was created by previous version of iTunes. Have no idea where to look for this file in Ubuntu or simply download the old lib file... For version 64bit playonlinux says that installation crashed with `POL_` error. Trying to install additional POL modules while creating a virtual space failed. Trying to use `wine ./iTunes64Setup.exe` crashes because my `wine` wasn't built with 64bit apps support. I tried to `./configure --enable-win64` to install [wine64](http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine64) from sources, but got error like `YYLEX is undefined`. Following suggestions in another stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262531/trouble-building-gcc-4-6) it still fails on `make depend && make` even after installing `flex` and `bison` packages and `make distclean`.
**Now, the question is what is the best way to install** `.ipa` **app on my iphone using ad-hoc method without itunes or how to install itunes on Ubuntu 14.04 so that it's possible?**.
There is also [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496733/does-itunes-work-well-on-ubuntu) to try `libimobiledevice4`, but I don't get it how can I just copy-paste an app.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to install *.ipa* app on your *iPhone* without *iTunes* you may want to take a look at [*TestFlightApp*](https://www.testflightapp.com/). You can upload your adhoc apps to there and then install in on your device directly from the device without *iTunes* or *Xcode*.

Comment: is there any solution without using side services ?

Comment: @boldnik install windows?

Comment: Thanks @Novarg :) This is the last solution I tried. Windows in VirtualBox. Not the best one I admit...